# Template that iterates through channel entries and outputs categories that are selected for each entry

Tags: channel-entries, templates, categories

I've found it perfectly possible to output a list of all of the categories for a channel, or a list of all of the categories that are not empty for a channel. But when I am iterating through the different posts of a channel, how can I output for each post only the categories that are checked for that specific channel entry?

I've read through the documentation pretty thoroughly, http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html, and I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

I'm trying to spit this information out as JSON... to put it into context, below is what I have as a base. Ideally I would like to nest an array in my associative array that contains all of the categories for that channel entry.

```
<?php

  $entries = array();

  {exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel_entries" dynamic="yes"}
    $entries[] = array(
      'name' => '{entry_name}',
      'description' => '{description}'          
    );
  {/exp:channel:entries}

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($entries, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  exit;

?>
```

Any help/creative problem solving that you all can offer will be greatly appreciated! Let me know if I can provide any more details to help you, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got bogged down with `{exp:channel:categories}` when I was getting started; in this context, you'll want to use the [`{categories}` tag pair within `{exp:channel:entries}`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories).

Comment: I'm surprised how many times I've seen this question -- I've just added a [comment to the docs for Channel Categories](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html#12229) in hopes of saving others the frustration down the road.

Comment: Yeah, it really, really threw me for a loop when I was getting started... I'm sure there are still some crazy templates out there floating around with really odd looking {exp:channel:category} loops in them.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot @NickBenson ! That was exactly it... nothing too it :-)